# How do I get the items to refresh in the Flowcover example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The [Flowcover](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m) example code provides an OpenGL ES implementation of the coverflow effect.  How can I refresh the images used in that example?

I have tried `[view reloadData];` but that didn't refresh the images. What else should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you elaborate a bit on where you want to refresh the images? Are you reloading a new set of images you want to display?
Note that there is a cache in the class FlowCover that you might need to empty. There is currently no interface to do just that so you might want to add the next method to the class DataCache:

```
- (void) emptyCache {
  [fDictionary removeAllObjects];
  [fAge removeAllObjects];
}
```

Remember to send `setNeedsDisplay` to the View after modifying any data it depends on.